# How to implement bootstrap tour on wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, bootstrap-tour

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap Tour an a Wordpress site with the Bootstrap Theme but so far every time I try to link the stylesheets (CSS) and the JavaScrit it doesn't work. The page wont load the stylesheets or javascript.

All the setup works fine when i work locally but when i try to implemented on wordpress nothing works.

Is there a specific way I have to setup all the stylesheets and javascript on wordpress?

This is my header:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

    <?php if (is_search()) { ?>
       <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
    <?php } ?>

    <title>

    <?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?>

    </title>    
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/landing-page.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?> 

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Any errors on the browser console?

Comment: The console errors are not related to the stylesheets or javascript. The erros are mission images related.

Comment: What's a "Bootstrap Tour"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `child theme`, `get_template_directory_uri()` will give the path of the `parent theme`

For child theme, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.